# CocoaLibSpotify playback crashes after a few seconds

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I followed the SimplePlayer example project while integrating it in my own test project. Logging in and searching for tracks already works perfectly, but when I try to play a song like SimplePlayer it crashes after 1-2 seconds of playback with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on two different locations in `SPSession.m` (see picture below). Here is the code that starts playback:

```
SPTrack *track = [allTracks objectAtIndex:currentTrack];
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {
    [playbackManager playTrack:track callback:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't play Spotify Track" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            spotifyTrack = track;
        }
    }];
}];
```

Note: I handle the playback of the songs in a custom class `SpotifyPlayer` via Singleton pattern.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: crash locations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming SimplePlayer doesn't crash in the same way. That code shows that you're either over-releasing your SPSession instance, or that the object you set as the session's delegate has been released without the delegate being set to `nil`. Double check your memory management and object lifetimes.

Comment: thank you so much! turns out i dismissed the viewcontroller that was the delegate before setting a new one.