# Crash in CocoaLibSpotify without any Log

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am using Cocoalib spotify in my app..its getting crash without any log..Please see the attached image[image]

here message was "06:46:42.789 I [offline-mgr:2032] 0 files are locked. 0 images are locked" about to print....

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaLibSpotify playback crashes after a few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416747/cocoalibspotify-playback-crashes-after-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with how you're setting the Session's `delegate` property. Double-check your memory management and make sure you're setting the `delegate` to `nil` if the object you previously set is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..i am new to the Objective c..this is my code [[SPSession sharedSession] setDelegate:self]; when i set delegate.i added this code in my 'ViewDidLoad'..i want to know where to set 'nil'..and when ?